# AS3 Change curve to Symbol Hitbox

Tags: actionscript-3, line, draw, curve

I have two draggable objects, and when your drag one them it generates a line based off where your mouse is, and the line is anchored to the other object. What Id like this code to do, is generate the line at the rear of the symbol

I got this

[image]

but I need this

[image]

```
       if ((mouseX-targetPointX<0 && mouseY-targetPointY>0) || (mouseX-targetPointX>=0 && mouseY-targetPointY<=0)) {
        line.moveTo(mouseX-offset,mouseY-offset);
        line.curveTo(mouseX-offset,targetPointY-offset,targetPointX-offset,targetPointY-offset);
        line.lineTo(targetPointX+offset,targetPointY+offset);
        line.curveTo(mouseX+offset,targetPointY+offset,mouseX+offset,mouseY+offset);
    } else {
        line.moveTo(mouseX-offset,mouseY+offset);
        line.curveTo(mouseX-offset,targetPointY+offset,targetPointX-offset,targetPointY+offset);
        line.lineTo(targetPointX+offset,targetPointY-offset);
        line.curveTo(mouseX+offset,targetPointY-offset,mouseX+offset,mouseY-offset);
    }
    line.endFill();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using the mouse position as reference to draw your curve, you can use a custom `Point` object with the coordinates from where you want the curve to start from.

```
moveTo(myPoint.x, myPoint.y);
```

You can create any `Point` you want, for example at (50,200) using the relative coordinates from your `Sprite`, and then find the global coordinates using `localToGlobal`.

```
var globalPoint:Point = mySprite.localToGlobal(new Point(50,200));
trace(globalPoint.x,globalPoint.y);
```